# Connecting to a MySQL database on a network

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, database, lan

I am working on a program which is mainly working with a mysql database.

I want to share the mysql database over the network so the users who are opening the client application can access the database and make changes simultaneously.

I have no idea how to share it over the network. I found this connection string on the internet but I don't understand it.

```
ConnectionString = @"Data Source=192.168.0.1,1433\SQLEXPRESS;user id=Rula;
  password=****;AttachDbFilename=\\192.168.0.1\Release\WEPA.mdf;
  Connection Timeout=30;Integrated Security=SSPI;user instance=true";
```

Comment: In case you are wondering, I removed the password from the connection string.

Comment: thanks it was not mine anyway :)

Comment: That should make you even more worried about passing it on...

Answer (score 4):

The connection string you are showing in the question is used for a connection to SQL Server.

[Look here for MySQL](http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql) connection strings.

**EDIT**

Aditionally:

If you are going to allow multiple users to connect simultaneously be aware of concurrency issues. Make sure you understand locking and (optimistic) concurrency control.

Comment: And dont use direct access at MySQL ,use a Web Service or WCF as a Data Presentation Layer .

Answer (score 2):

That connection string isn't MySql, it's Microsoft SQL Server (MSSQL).

If you have a MySql database, then you have a MySql Server running somewhere, which handles multiple connections automatically.

You should just be able to connect to it through the [MySQL .net Connector](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/).